# Firebase Forge won't update intermittently

Tags: firebase

I am having an issue with Forge. I have been using Firebase/Forge for quite a while now. I have never encountered this issue before. Now when I try to edit a value, I click to get into edit mode then input new value and hit enter. The new value never gets updated regardless of how many times I hit enter. If the field blurs and I go somewhere else, the new value will be displayed but the actual value stored in the database is not updated. If I refresh the page, the old value will then be shown. Anyone else seen this?

Comment: This issue seems more appropriate for Firebase support than StackOverflow. Try contacting support@firebase.com.

Comment: Ok.  Just thought maybe others have may have seen this.